# Can a SSRS hosted report trigger an email?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I was looking for a way to host a report on a server that would have a user specify an email as a parameter. Once this report was run, I want to attach the results as a pdf and send it to the email specified by the user.

I know that that you can send emails in SSRS through standard subscriptions or DDS, but is it possible to send the email to the address specified by the user in the report?

Comment: A data driven subscription is what you need but you wouldn't run the report, the user would put the email address somewhere (in the database) that would result in the subscription being run and sent to the address. Of course, this is only possible in Enterprise edition natively.